# How to send XML as express response?

Tags: javascript, express, soap

I'm building some transport tracker web app with express as my server side and I'm using an API to get bus information (Israeli DMV public api)..
Unfortunately this API supports only SOAP requests and responses so I'm sending a request with a XML body and get a XML reponse..

The Problem is that I can't understand how to send this reponse to the client, I'm doing this (after searching the internet for how to do this) -

```
router.get('/getbusesinfo', function(req, res, next) {
    var requestBody = requestTemplate
    console.log(requestBody)
    fetch(URL, {method: "POST", headers: HEADERS, body: requestBody}).then(ApiRes => {res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml'); res.send(xml(ApiRes.body()))})
    });
```

When I'm trying to fetch the result from my browser like this:

```
fetch('/busInfo/getbusesinfo').then(response => ApiRes = Response)
```

And that returns nothing..

BTW I'm very new to express so sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Use a SOAP client library instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap

Comment: Have you try to make a console.log on resolve part of your promise on server to be sure that it is called instead of a ejected error?